# Tensorflow's Tutorial GAN not Working for CIFAR-10

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [original tutorial GAN](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/dcgan) works on the default mnist dataset, but when I tried to modify it to work with cifar10 it outputs nonsensical images.

I didn't really change much (besides tracking losses for graphing purposes) beyond the generator which I needed to change the dimensions from 28x28 for mnist to 32x32 for cifar10:

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(8*8*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((8, 8, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 8, 8, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 8, 8, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 16, 16, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 32, 32, 3)

    return model
```

For example, I get this output from the modified tutorial GAN:
[image: gan tutorial output1]

With this as the loss:

[image: gan tutorial loss1]

The rest of the outputs for each epoch before and after are very similar; mostly white images with some colored pixels here and there.

Link to the full [modified tutorial notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NWUrPJLLVvA-THpv2XqEgYeemuFl3Qj-) if anyone wants to run it themselves.

Any ideas of what I can change to make the GAN output distinguishable images?

Comment: are you sure you are running everythin as is should? The loss is weird. How discrimitaror performs on not generated input?

Comment: GANs are notoriously unstable/difficult to train. There are many papers/posts out there listing "tricks" to stabilize them, for example [this one](https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks). For datasets more challenging than MNIST, you will probably need to employ such tricks to get your networks to train properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same, and experienced the same problem. Finally, I found a great CIFAR-10 DCGAN tutorial here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-generative-adversarial-network-for-a-cifar-10-small-object-photographs-from-scratch/ . I plan to modify this to use GradientTape like the original Tensorflow tutorial and find the difference, but I also uploaded it to kaggle, so you can do your own experiments if you think: https://www.kaggle.com/laszlofazekas/cifar10-dcgan-example .